# Angular2 build process (npm install) failing on 'gulp pubget.dart'

Tags: angular

Following the [build steps](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/DEVELOPER.md), when I run `npm install`, I end up with this error:

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'object-assign'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/bearfriend/Sites/angular2/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/gulp-util/lib/PluginError.js:5:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

---

Here are some additonal logs:

```
verbose stack Error: angular@2.0.0-alpha.21 postinstall: `webdriver-manager update && bower install && gulp pubget.dart && tsd reinstall --config modules/angular2/tsd.json && tsd reinstall --config\
 tools/tsd.json`
329 verbose stack Exit status 8
329 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/Users/bearfriend/.nvm/v0.10.38/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:213:16)
329 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
329 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/bearfriend/.nvm/v0.10.38/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:24:14)
329 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
329 verbose stack     at maybeClose (child_process.js:766:16)
329 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:833:5)
330 verbose pkgid angular@2.0.0-alpha.21
331 verbose cwd /Users/bearfriend/Sites/angular2
332 error Darwin 14.1.0
333 error argv "node" "/Users/bearfriend/.nvm/v0.10.38/bin/npm" "install"
334 error node v0.10.38
335 error npm  v2.9.0
336 error code ELIFECYCLE
337 error angular@2.0.0-alpha.21 postinstall: `webdriver-manager update && bower install && gulp pubget.dart && tsd reinstall --config modules/angular2/tsd.json && tsd reinstall --config tools/tsd.json\
`
337 error Exit status 8
338 error Failed at the angular@2.0.0-alpha.21 postinstall script 'webdriver-manager update && bower install && gulp pubget.dart && tsd reinstall --config modules/angular2/tsd.json && tsd reinstall --c\
onfig tools/tsd.json'.
```

I'm not sure what exactly I'm looking at here, so any help would be appreciated. I do not plan on doing any work with Dart, so if this can be ignored or pulled out that'd be fine, but I would like to get everything set up properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I'm still not sure if this is a bug with angular or an npm issue, here's what I did:

Reasoned from the error message,

```
cd node_modules/gulp/node_modules/gulp-util
```

Confirm with `package.json` that it depends on object-assign.
Confirm in node_modules that it isn't installed.

```
npm install
cd ../../../..
npm install
```

Voila! Continue with [build process](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/DEVELOPER.md)